# Angularjs $resource to match up with Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to make an AngularJS `$resource` that matches up to these routes in a Rails API:

```
  search_notes GET    /notes/search/:term(.:format)  lesson_notes/notes#search
         notes GET    /notes(.:format)               lesson_notes/notes#index
               POST   /notes(.:format)               lesson_notes/notes#create
          note GET    /notes/:id(.:format)           lesson_notes/notes#show
               PATCH  /notes/:id(.:format)           lesson_notes/notes#update
               DELETE /notes/:id(.:format)           lesson_notes/notes#destroy
```

This is what I have now, which doesn't work:

```
LessonNotes.factory("Note", ["$resource", function($resource) {
  return $resource("lesson_notes/notes/:id:action/:term", {
      id: "@id",
      action: "@action",
      term: "@term"
    }, {
      query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true },
      update: { method: 'PATCH' },
      destroy: { method: 'DELETE' },
      search: { method: 'GET', params: {
          action: 'search',
          term: '@term'
        },
        isArray: true
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Here's the error I get:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://localhost:3000/lesson_notes/notes/search?0=i&1=n&2=t&3=r&4=o&5=d&6=u&7=c&8=e"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my service was set up correctly but I was calling search incorrectly:

This was my **mistake**:

```
var results = Note.search($scope.searchTerm);
```

This is a **correct**:

```
var results = Note.search({term: $scope.searchTerm});
```

---

By the way, this code snippet really helped figure this problem out: https://coderwall.com/p/rd0c8w